# Compare dates in WHERE request within QUERY in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to query a range that returns only rows where the date in `Column S` is older than the date in `Column D`

All dates in the sheet are already formatted `yyyy-mm-dd` but I can't seem to find any suggestions on how to use `WHERE` with a range of dates, rather than either a single date or a specific cell.

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:W11536,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K where date '"&text(Sheet1!D2:D,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' > date'"&text(Sheet1!S2:S,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

This is giving me an `N/A` error: "Query completed with an empty output."

When I make it `<` rather than `>` it populates without error, though it's not showing the desired results. There should be valid data for `>`.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with the shortest formula and create a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone withe the link, providing sample input data.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is enough when you're comparing two columns

```
=query(A:H,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H where C>H")
```

(although I couldn't find any rows that satisfied the criteria in your test sheet)

I think what is actually happening is that it is just comparing the first two dates so you either get all of the data or nothing.